# adjusting input field - places total value in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is a basic HTML layout that contains two input fields and one div with the class of 'output'. What I want to know is how to make the div with the class of 'output' be updated with the multiplication of the two spinners upon change. So as the values are adjusted and changed the answer is updated in real time.

Thank you guys for the help. I'm new to the whole javascript thing which I'm assuming this will require.

```
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>


<body>

    <div class="pagewrap">

        <form id="totalRenderTime">

            <fieldset>

                <div class="item">
                    <label>Count</label>
                    <input type="number" min="0" max="99999999" step="1" value="100" />
                </div><!--END item -->

                <div class="item">
                    <label>Multiplier</label>
                    <input type="number" min="0" max="99999999" step="1" value="10" /> 
                </div><!--END item -->

                <div class="item">
                    <label class="highlight">Total Render Time</label>
                    <div class="output">1000</div>
                </div><!--END item -->

            </fieldset>
        </form>

    </div><!--END pagewrap -->  

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added Fiddle here for your solution http://jsfiddle.net/8nhmU/16/

Source:

```
<div class="pagewrap">

        <form id="totalRenderTime">

            <fieldset>

                <div class="item">
                    <label>Count</label>
                    <input id="txtfirst" type="number" min="0" max="99999999" step="1" value="100" />
                </div><!--END item -->

                <div class="item">
                    <label>Multiplier</label>
                    <input id="txtSecond" type="number" min="0" max="99999999" step="1" value="10" /> 
                </div><!--END item -->

                <div class="item">
                    <label class="highlight">Total Render Time</label>
                    <div class="output">1000</div>
                </div><!--END item -->

            </fieldset>
        </form>

    </div><!--END pagewrap -->
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txtfirst, #txtSecond").change(function(){
     var result=$("#txtfirst").val()* $("#txtSecond").val();
    $(".output").text(result);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("input").change(function() {
var mul=1;
$('input').each(function(){
mul=mul*parseInt($(this).val());
})
$('.output').html(mul);
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tVupx/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use **onkeyup** event in javascript

```
<script>
function showTotal()
{
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=parseInt(document.getElementById("count").value)*parseInt(document.getElementById("multipy").value);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="pagewrap">
<form id="totalRenderTime">
<fieldset>
<div class="item">
<label>Count</label>
<input type="number" id="count" min="0" max="99999999" step="1" value="100" onkeyup="showTotal();" />
</div><!--END item -->
<div class="item">
<label>Multiplier</label>
<input id="multipy" type="number" min="0" max="99999999" step="1" value="10" onkeyup="showTotal();"  /> 
</div><!--END item -->
<div class="item">
<label class="highlight">Total Render Time</label>
<div class="output" id="output">1000</div>
</div><!--END item -->
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>

</body>
```