# parsing from an input perform calculation and display in a readonly input

Tags: jquery

I need to calculate the amount of my item * the quantity. I know I need to do a change function but I don't know where to start. I am having trouble parsing the input type="number" and the myItem.Price(which is from my javascript object if anyone can please help I'd be greatful.

```
    $('#add1').click(function () {
    var selected1 = ($('#produceList option:selected').index() - 1);
    myItem1 = pdata[selected1];
    $('#itembox').append('<div id="thep">' + '<p class = "product">' + myItem1.Name + '    ' + myItem1.Price + '</p>' + '<label for="howMAny">Qty:</label>' + '<input id="howMany" type="number" min="0" max="10" value=0>' + '<label for="thisMany">Price:</label>' + '<input type="text" id ="thisMany" value = "$0.00"readonly>' + '</div>');



});
```

Comment: just have a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108594/adjusting-input-field-places-total-value-in-div/21108725#21108725 .......

Comment: have your tried `parseInt();`

Comment: I have but the readonly input isn't changing. I looked on jquery.com it's just that what I'm trying to do is a little diferent. I'm not too good with figuring this stuff out maybe you can show me some code of how u would do it

Comment: @BibyAugustine thats a great example thanks

Comment: @chrisp54 Thnx....... :)